# iPhone Objective-C self question

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In a simple UITableView I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Pictures",@"Video",@"Text",@"Map",nil];
  self.selectionList = array;
  [array release];

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
...
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
  }

  NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
  cell.textLabel.text = [selectionList objectAtIndex:row];

  return cell;
}
```

My question is this, why in the viewDidLoad section, does it need to be self.selectionList and not just selectionList??  I mean, the whole point is to pass the contents of the array we just created into the selectionList array, so why the self?

Comment: Read up on properties and Objective-C memory management

Comment: A side note: `viewDidLoad` should have the parent call first (as the first line).

Comment: @Kevin: Shouldn't make a difference - in Apple's docs it's often called not at all.

Comment: @Eiko I think it is a fairly common convention to call super on anything doing initialization first, and super on anything doing destruction last. It might not make a difference for `viewDidLoad` but it will for many other similar calls.

Comment: Thanks everyone for all of the help, I wish I could say that I completely understand all of your explanations but I am still a little fuzzy on all of this.  The fact that I know it is a setter/getter and memory management issue, at least I have a rough idea of what is going on.

Comment: @Kevin: The construction/destruction rule is a good rule of thumb!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you use 'self' it will use the property setter and getter. That means that if you create a property as being retain it will allow you to `release` (as the setter will call a `retain`). If you didn't use the setter (I'm assuming that it is a retain property), you could also write the above like this (but I wouldn't recommend it):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  selectionList = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Pictures",@"Video",@"Text",@"Map",nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [sectionList release];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: This will leak an array if it was initialized already, i.e. in -init

Comment: Yeah, I was assuming the array was not initialized but this is true.

Comment: viewDidLoad can be called more than once, i.e. in case of memory warnings. So if you do it manually, you need to do [selectionList release] before assigning the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Because self.selectionList uses a property (-> setter method) instead of directly accessing the instance variable. This makes it possible to overwrite this variable access in a subclass what would not be possible with direct ivar access. Using properties is in general the cleaner approach (data encapsulation/information hiding).

As mentioned in the other comments: Without the property you have to care about memory management at every point you set the ivar. What will in this case properly mean that you have to drop the release.

Answer (score 1):

Using the dot-syntax for the (most likely) `ratain`ing or `copy`ing property has three effects: It assigns or copies the array (depending on the declaration), makes sure it gets a retain message so that it will stay alive, and - also important - `release`s the old array so that it doesn't leak.

If you wanted to go without the dot syntax, then you'd have to do all these steps manually.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that my [array release]; call here is superfluous?  The dot-syntax is doing it for me?

Comment: No. The code is fine as is. The release balances the alloc/init. Please read the Memory Management Guide - I cannot recommend it enough. It's worth reading more than once. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The difference here is how the memory management works.  Assuming the `@property` selectionList is defined as retain, calling `self.selectionList = something;` implicitly calls `[selectionList retain]`.

In this specific example, doing simply `selectionList = something;` would most likely cause a crash down the line, since the object is being released.

Answer (score 0):

In this instance, it needs to be self.selectionList, as this is using a setter method (I presume you've used a property with the retain attribute in the header and then synthesied selectionList in the implementation). It's effectively the same as doing...

```
[self setSelectionList:array];
```

...if that makes sense.

Otherwise, you'd simply be assigning the array to a class instance variable and you'd need to do a retain and subsequent release to ensure that it was managed correctly.

Comment: It wasn't me, but the only issue I see with this answer is that, since he `alloc`ed memory, he doesn't actually need to do a retain (as it's not autoreleased), just a subsequent release. If he had used the setter here, in addition to allocing memory, he'd have a double retain. The proper pattern is to `alloc`, the assign using the setter, then release the original.

Comment: @Sam - Ah, yup. Thanks for the heads-up - I'll try to explain more clearly next time. :-)